# What is the dual function of the $f(x) = \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i)$?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> I have always assumed that the dual of  $$f(x) = \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i),
>  x \in \Delta^N$$ is $$f(y) =  \ln(\sum_i e^{y_i}), y \in
>  \mathbb{R}^N$$ (and vice versa, the other direcion is *extremely* well
>   known)

**However, in MM Optimization Algorithms by Kenneth Lange, it writes:**

[image]

However, notice the domain is $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$

> Can anyone please confirm the dual of neg entropy function $$f(x) =
>  \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i), x \in \Delta^N$$
>
> References are much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are both correct. There are two conjugate pairs:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases} \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i) & \text{if } x \in \Delta^N \\ \infty & \text{else}\end{cases} \\
f^*(y) &=  \log\left(\sum_i e^{y_i}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \begin{cases} \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i) & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ \\ \infty & \text{else}\end{cases} \\
g^*(y) &=  \sum_i e^{y_i-1}
\end{align*}
$$
See, e.g., [Table 1](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2016/09/5638.pdf).